# File separator for windows and unix

Tags: c, windows, linux, path

I have a code that should run on both windows and unix systems (Mac, linux etc.) and I want to access / delete some files in a relative path, is there a way to construct the path in a way that will be compatible for both OSs (like Java's `File.separator`)?

The closest thing that I though about is something like that:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#define FILE_SEPARATOR   "\\"
#else
#define FILE_SEPARATOR   "/"
#endif

//in windows - ".\\filedir\\filename.txt"
//in *nix - "./filedir/filename.txt"
const char * mypath = "." FILE_SEPARATOR "filedir" FILE_SEPARATOR "filename.txt";
```

**EDIT**

After reading the answers / comments below - I would like to add that a confirmation that windows XP or newer compliance with POSIX regarding this is enough for me.

Comment: I believe there is a boost path construction method but I don't know its name right now.

Comment: Modern Windows (Vista, 7, Server 2008 for sure; XP I'm not sure) accept `/` as path separator too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows supports a POSIX-compliant path separator.

This means that you can safely use the forward slash `/` when building your path and consuming Windows API or C IO functions.

However, if your code acts as a library and exposes an API which accepts and returns paths, you may have to posixify input paths and unposixify return paths. This will add a slight burden but will feel more native to your consumers.

Comment: Are you sure this is true for Win XP? Do you have some confirmation for that? (I'm not saying that it's not true, but I can't be sure by only check it on my computer)

Comment: It works on Windows 3.1, 95, 98, ME, NT, XP, Vista, 7, ...  The problem child on Windows is the DOS CMD.EXE program, which treats `/` as the indicator of an option (analogous to `-` on Unix).  But the actual C APIs (or the system calls behind them) are OK with either `/` or `\\` (slash or backslash - and bother Markdown!) as the separator.

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is to just use `/` on both. Even though Windows requires `\` when you're specifying a path separator on the command line, when passed in an argument `CreateFile`, you can use '/' as the path separator with no problems at all.

This has been true all the way back to MS-DOS 2.0 (the first to support subdirectories and paths at all). Though it didn't last very long, there were even versions of DOS that allowed you to change the `switchar` to '-', so it allowed `/` as the path separator even on the command line.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I am missing something, the C library in Windows will accept the "/" separator.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to other answers, you could use some C portable layer library, like e.g. [Glib](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/glib/) (from Gtk) which offers you a platform agnostic set of functions for such purposes.

Comment: Use `glib` is a bit broad, care to mention the function ?

Comment: Here is the link in case anyone was curious: https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Standard-Macros.html#G-DIR-SEPARATOR-S:CAPS